# can some one please verify mistakes

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have a line  -

```
NM1*85*2*NIVE HEALTH PHARMA, P.C. 428*****XX*1679857825~
```

and from this I want to extract 1679857825 and append it to make a new column name df['npi']
and for that I am writing code -

```
if 'NM1*85*' in line and (line.split('NM1*85*')[1].split('*')[7][-9:].strip('~')[:5]).isnumeric() and (line.split('NM1*85*')[1].split('*')[7][0:9]).isnumeric():
    row['NPI'] = (line.split('NM1*85*')[1].split('*')[7].translate({ord('~'):None}))
    claims_yos.append(row)
```

but my output is coming 0 where as it should be 1679857825. can some one verify the mistakes

Comment: Please choose a proper title, I was just about to flag as spam based on it.

Comment: And please update your code into a [mre].

Comment: Side note: writing that many things on one line, fully of arbitrary magic numbers and without any whitespace, virtually _guarantees_ that code won't do what you want it to. Clarity counts.

Comment: One example is not enough to understand what you are trying to do. Is this a packed field delimited by asterisks? Are there always the same number of fields? Does the first always consist of two uppercase letters and one digit? Are the second and third always numeric? Are there ever values between `428` and `XX`? Can you provide examples of other values, with expected outputs? Examples of invalid lines? To get `1679857825` out of `NM1*85*2*NIVE HEALTH PHARMA, P.C. 428*****XX*1679857825~` I can just do `if "1679857825" in line`...

Comment: yes , every line is filled by delimited asterisk , and its in the same format for other thousand examples

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trivial regular expression as follows:

```
import re
my_string = 'NM1*85*2*NIVE HEALTH PHARMA, P.C. 428*****XX*1679857825~'
fa = re.findall(r'(\d+)', my_string)
print(fa[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
1679857825
```

Comment: thanks for the help but what if we have thousand line as given above and out of that I want to have thousand values

Comment: @geeky_buoy You'll probably need a loop of some kind. Your question is too vague to be able to answer in any detail